# eigenvector of a multiplication operator

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\phi\in L^\infty(\mu)$. Define $M_\phi:L^2(\mu)\to L^2(\mu)$ by $M_\phi(f)=\phi f$. What conditions are needed on $\phi$ so that $M_\phi$ has an eigenvector? If $\phi$ is a constant clearly $M_\phi$ has an eigenvector. But even if $M_\phi$ has an eigenvector, it is not clear that $\phi$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\phi$ is constant on a subset of positive measure, then a function whose support is only there will also be an eigenvector. For instance if the space is $[0,2]$ with the Lebesgue measure, $\phi=\chi_{[0,1]}$, and $f(x) = \max \{ 0,1-x \}$, then $f$ is an eigenvector of $M_\phi$.